# Calling and releasing CLLocationManager With ARC

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

My app should get the user's current location only one time.

It's doing it successfully using the location manager and a delegate. Once i get the location for the first time my delegate calls the manager to `stopUpdatingLocation`.

Since I'm using ARC, and I keep an instance of this class during all the time my app runs, my CLLocationManager instance stays in memory.

I know GPS services are quite power consuming, but does it have the same effect while i actually don't consume more events? does it keep on working?

I want to know if i should add some logic to release it.

Comment: use can use  self.locationManager = nil;

Comment: Beware of only using the first location - it may not be very accurate - You can check the horizontalAccuracy property of the CLLocation to determine if you want to wait for additional updates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Following...

```
-(void)updateLoc
{
    if (self.locationManager != nil)
    {
        [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
        self.locationManager.delegate = nil;
        self.locationManager = nil;
    }

    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];    
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.headingFilter = 1;

    self.locationManager.distanceFilter=10.0;
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}


-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    self.locationManager = nil;
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{//Use if you are supporting iOS 5
    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    self.locationManager = nil;
}
```

Comment: `didUpdateLocation:toLocation` is deprecated - you only need to implement `didUpdateLocations:`